# how can i make it so that a cell stays blank when the cell it is referencing is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a maths quiz for a group of year 6 pupils and I have used `if` function to to put a "correct" or "incorrect" next to the question depending on the answer they give. However, when the pupil hasn't answered the question, it says incorrect even though the pupil hasn't actually put in an answer yet. I want it to be blank until he/she puts in his/her answer.

[image: here is a screenshot of my quiz]

help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extra `IF` function around your existing formula, e.g. for your scenario change the formula in `I12` to the following

`=IF(H12="","",IF(H12=9,"correct","incorrect"))`

Comment: ("gasp") thankyou so much i've been struggling for so long. it works wonderfully.

Comment: sure there you go

Comment: can i just quickly ask how i can add up all the correct answers and put it out of 10 (e.g.) in the "total" section of the spreadsheet, all automatically.

Comment: Try using this formula: `=COUNTIF(I9:I17,"correct")&"/10"`

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest a solution which help you to manage the Quiz properly. First Check the Screen Shot.

[image]

I've created a **Helper Column** and the **Formula is** ,

=IF(K227="","Not Answred",IF(K227=H227,"Correct","InCorrect"))

My **Data Range** is **H227 to L326**.

**Helper Column** is **H**. **Result is** in Column **L**.

**NB:** Now what you have to do before you start Quiz. 
**Write the Formula in Cell L227 & Drag it till L236**. Initially Formula reflects **Not Answered**.

**Then Hide the Helper Column**.

As soon as students will answer Excel will justify with **Correct** or **Incorrect**.

**Hope this help you in better way. I've posted the solution after been tested by me.**

Comment: If you wish I can suggest you method help you to clear the Answer Cells.

Comment: Please write the REASON in case any body Vote Negative to my Answer,!!